# { "error": "inputs is a plain value/list, but expecting an object as multiple input tensors required as per tensorinfo_map" }

Tags: python, json, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am using tensorflow serving to deploy my model .

my tensorinfo map is

> saved_model_cli show --dir /export/1/ --tag_set serve
>   --signature_def serving_default

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  inputs['length_0'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_INT32
      shape: (-1)
      name: serving_default_length_0:0
  inputs['length_1'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_INT32
      shape: (-1)
      name: serving_default_length_1:0
  inputs['length_2'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_INT32
      shape: (-1)
      name: serving_default_length_2:0
  inputs['tokens_0'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_STRING
      shape: (-1, -1)
      name: serving_default_tokens_0:0
  inputs['tokens_1'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_STRING
      shape: (-1, -1)
      name: serving_default_tokens_1:0
  inputs['tokens_2'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_STRING
      shape: (-1, -1)
      name: serving_default_tokens_2:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
  outputs['alignment'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, 1, -1, -1)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall_8:0
  outputs['length'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_INT32
      shape: (-1, 1)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall_8:1
  outputs['log_probs'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, 1)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall_8:2
  outputs['tokens'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_STRING
      shape: (-1, 1, -1)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall_8:3
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

I am making a curl request

```
curl -X POST -i 'http://192.168.1.16:8501/v1/models/export:predict' --data '{ "signature_name":  "serving_default",  "inputs": [{ "tokens_0" :["text text text text text text text text text text"], "length_0": [1], "tokens_1": ["01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01"], "length_1": [1], "tokens_2": ["4 4 4 1 1 4 4 4 4 4"], "length_2": [1]}]}'
```

I want to know where I am going wrong in passing data. what should be the request json format.

This particular model is a multi feature model , which takes three strings as input and than gives one string as output.

Answer (score 7):

You are passing your input in row format, so if you replace "inputs" to "instances" everything should work fine, [See here for the difference between row and columnar format](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_rest#specifying_input_tensors_in_row_format)

Comment: I got problem as well with multi modal inputs. My input is a list where 1st item should be batch x height x width x 3, and 2nd item is a string. The output would be a list where 1st item is the usual softmax prediction, and 2nd item is the same string passed. Whats the format of json input be like?